# Can any video card drive two 30" monitors as long as it has two dual-link DVI ports?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

My PCIe x16 ATI card has 512MB and two dual-link DVI ports. It runs a 30" display at 2560x1600 and also a 21" display at 1680 x 1050.

If instead I drive dual 30" monitors then one still runs at 2560x1600 but the other is garbled above 1280x960.

Why might this be and what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm also curious what it would take to drive the 21" as well - if I could fit all three on my desk. Note, of the three the only interfaces in common are DVI and VGA.

Comment: You need a "dual head" video card that supports dual link on both DVI video outputs.

Comment: @Moab the [specs](http://www.cnet.com/products/ati-radeon-hd-2600-xt/specs/) of the 2600 XT do say 2 x DVI-I (dual link)"

Comment: My guess is - the card just does not have enough memory, and I should get a card like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500357&ignorebbr=1)

Comment: dual link is only needed for larger 27 and up high res monitors, strange they said it supports it on both heads when it cannot do it because of memory. Let us know if the new card solves it.

Comment: I reworded the question to make it more generic and less likely to become obsolete. If someone will un-close it then I will post the answer which is "Try upgrading to a more modern, 2GB card". Since I did indeed purchase the "GT 730 2GB card" and now I can run both 30" monitors at native resolution. Seems like a useful thing to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size is less important than resolution. Without knowing what the specific graphics card is, its pretty hard to tell. I could easily run a 50" plasma screen at 800x600 off an XT, and I'd need at least a mid range card card from 3 generations ago for a 4k display of any size.

Looking at the [specifications](https://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/ATI/HD_2600_XT/) looks like it *should* barely be able to run 2 2560x1600 displays. I'd consider a few possibilities - one of the output controllers is faulty, the cable is faulty, or there's some other bottleneck. Dual-link DVI certainly should be able to handle the resolution, as should more modern connectors.

Upgrading certainly would help tho whether this is to mitigate a weak or faulty card, I have not enough evidence to tell.

With a more modern system or the right setup you might get away with using a mix of onboard and discrete graphics (sandy bridge onwards) or more than one card. Depends on your setup and drivers tho.

Comment: The card (a  2600 XT in this case) was indeed either defective or insufficient, and a 2GB card (GeForce GT 730 2GB in this case) made both screens work perfectly. Thank you!